# how to show dob in dd-mm-yyyy in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

how to show dob in dd-mm-yyyy in javascript ?I am getting data from server in millisecond or long value.so I used `moment` to show DOB in DD-MMM-YYYY ..there is option to edit DOB , I also want to send update value or same value if it is not changed to server in milliseconds or long values .

I am getting this value from server

```
var x = '-2208988800000'
  var d = new Date(moment(new Date(parseInt(x)).toUTCString()).format('DD-MMM-YYYY'));
```

but when I try to send dob value to server without changing DOB like this
**while sending long value to server**

```
var x2 = moment(new Date(d).toUTCString()).format('x');

//X2 should give same value of x
```

so I am not ble to send correct data to server .Please suggest how to show DOB In DD-MMM-YYYY and send value in milliseconds 
here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/1VOQAH6Jk65QNNU2hYpN?p=preview

Comment: Your code is formatting the date via Moment but then it turns right around and makes a new Date object from that string.

Comment: @Joy Flagged your post for moderator intervention. This question is well formed and follows Stack Overflow's well formed post, if anyone is going to down vote, at least leave a reason. I up voted to offset the down vote.

Comment: I think the best solution is not to store a date of birth with milliseconds in your database. You probably don't care what millisecond your user was born during, so this is a waste of space - just store the date. If you're using SQL, use the DATE type.

Comment: In `new Date(moment(new Date(parseInt(x)).toUTCString()).format('DD-MMM-YYYY'))` you are turning a string into a Date, then into a string, then into a Moment object, back to a string, then a Date again. It’s equivalent to `new Date(parseInt(x))`.

Comment: Assuming *d* is in the format YYYY-MM-DD, then `moment(new Date(d).toUTCString()).format('x')` is equivalent to `+new Date(d)` or `new Date(d).getTime()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your input value is indeed exactly as shown here, a *string* containing a value based on the Unix epoch in terms of milliseconds, then you can do this:

```
var x = '-2208988800000';
var m = moment.utc(x, 'x')
var s = m.format('DD-MMM-YYYY'); //=> '01-Jan-1900'
```

You can convert back to the original string like this:

```
var x = m.format('x');  //=> '-2208988800000'
```

If instead of a string you have a *number*, then it would be:

```
var x = -2208988800000;
var m = moment.utc(x);
var s = m.format('DD-MMM-YYYY'); //=> '01-Jan-1900'
```

You can convert back to the original number by using the `valueOf` function, or coercing to a number:

```
var x = m.valueOf();   //=> -2208988800000
var x = +m;            // shorthand (same result)
```

*Your person is 118 years old.  ;-)*

---

That said, I'm not sure why you have a birthdate in terms of milliseconds to begin with.  I tend to agree with Tim MacCabe's comment under your question.  Birthdates shouldn't be stored with such precision, or be assigned to any time or adjusted to UTC or any time zone.  Instead of `-2208988800000`, store a value such as `1900-01-01`.  Use whatever `DATE` type your database supports, and transfer it as a string in ISO8601 format (`"1900-01-01"`).  You could then reformat it if desired, like this:

```
var x = '1900-01-01';
var m = moment(x);
var s = m.format('DD-MMM-YYYY');  //=> '01-Jan-1900'
```

And back:

```
var x = m.format('YYYY-MM-DD');  //=> '1900-01-01'
```